# Moore Detector -1011, non-overlapping case

Tags: digital-logic, fpga, verilog, state-machines, sequence-detector

I am not able to figure out why the output goes low when I have done it properly.  I used the similar logic for Mealy.  It worked, but here it's not proper.

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ps
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    module sd(input clk,reset,x,output reg z);
    reg [1:0]ps,ns;
    parameter S0=0,S1=1,S2=2,S3=3,S4=4;
    
    always@(posedge(clk))
    begin
    if(reset)
    ps<=S0;
    else
    ps<=ns;
    end
    
    always@(posedge (clk))
    begin
    if(reset)
    z<=0;
    else
    z<=(ps==S4);
    end
    
    always@(ps,x)
    begin
    case(ps)
    
     S0 : ns  = x ? S1 : S0 ;
     S1 : ns = x ? S1 : S2 ;
     S2 : ns = x ? S3 : S0 ;
     S3 : ns = x ? S4 : S2 ;
     S4 : ns = x ? S1 : S0;
    endcase
    end
    endmodule
    
    module new();
    reg clk,reset,x;
    wire z;
    sd v( clk,reset,x, z);
    
    always #5 clk = ~ clk;  
    
    initial
    begin
    fork
    
    clk=1;
    reset=1;
    #15 reset=0;
    begin
    #15  x=1;
    #15 x=0;#10 x=1;#10 x=1;
    #300 $finish;
    end
    join 
    end
    endmodule
```

[image: Output Waveform]

Answer (score 2):

The main problem is that your state variable does not have enough bits to support the number of states in the FSM.  5 states requires at least 3 bits, but you only have 2 bits.  Change:

```
reg [1:0]ps,ns;
```

to:

```
reg [2:0]ps,ns;
```

Now the output signal (`z`) goes to 1:

[image: waves]

---

There is another problem lurking.  Your testbench has a potential simulation race condition.  You should drive the synchronous inputs in the testbench the same way you model the synchronous logic in the design:

- `@(posedge clk)`
- Nonblocking assignments: `<=`

Here is one way to rewrite the `initial` block:

```
initial begin
    fork   
        clk=1;
        reset=1;
        #15 reset=0;
        begin
            x = 0;
            repeat (3) @(posedge clk);
            x <= 1;
            repeat (1) @(posedge clk);
            x <= 0;
            repeat (1) @(posedge clk);
            x <= 1;
            #300 $finish;
        end
    join 
end
```